# Magento 2 ON PLP get the simple Product ID after the upate the variation in my custom widget

Tags: magento2, product, list-page, get-simple-product-id

> I have created a custom widget for all image rendering of the product image hover on the Product list page (category page). It works fine but for the configurable product, we have updated the swatch for simple product selections the images are updated so we need the selected product ID.  I have the parent product ID and selected attribute ID and option value.

> I tried the swatch-renderer js in my widget but it's not working. Maybe that is the scope of the change event.

> The second approach is from the Ajax call with parent product ID with attribute options values.

> Please share your thoughts on the same to find the simple product ID of the configurable product attribute selection on the list page from the js.

> Please find the reference video from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j8XLs28m6dw1AEt4a2sDNYTvL5sK8PVU/view)

Thanks.